# cannot delete /var/log/acpid file

Tags: linux, bash

I am the owner of this file, and have the right permission I think. Why can't I do the operations below:
(I have to delete it. My / is almost full.)

```
[root@DBsvr log]# ll -ah acpid
-rw-r----- 1 root root 84G Jun  1 14:14 acpid

[root@DBsvr ~]# rm -rf /var/log/acpid
rm: cannot remove `/var/log/acpid': Operation not permitted

[root@DBsvr ~]# > /var/log/acpid
-bash: /var/log/acpid: Operation not permitted

[root@DBsvr ~]# chmod 660 /var/log/acpid
chmod: changing permissions of `/var/log/acpid': Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change permissions and / or delete a file you need write permissions to the **parent directory** of the file.  Also, the file's attributes might come into play too (see `man chattr`).

Please note also that deleting a file while a process still has the file open won't free the disk space occupied by the file.  This is the case if you remove for example a log file while `syslogd` still tries to write to it.

Comment: Thanks, but I have the write permissions to the parent directory. File: `/var/log' Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x).

Comment: @张福星 Then check the attributes: `lsattr /var/log/acpid`.

Comment: I have tried stop acpid daemon before deleting. But it doesn't work.

Comment: lsattr /var/log/acpid -----a------- /var/log/acpid

Comment: @张福星 As far as I know `acpid` logs to `syslog`, not directly to a file.

Comment: @张福星 The `a` attribute is your problem. Try `chattr -a /var/log/acpid`.  That will allow you to remove the file.  But the space won't be freed if `syslog` is still writing to it.

Comment: @sato katsura is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Thank Sato Katsura for helping me.

```
[root@DBsvr log]# lsattr /var/log/acpid
-----a------- /var/log/acpid

[root@DBsvr log]# chattr -a /var/log/acpid
```

Then I can delete it.